# How to decrease number with default number on db

Tags: laravel

I have 2 table like User and Paidleave

in user I have **id , name ,email ,password , etc**

and in Paidleave I have **id , user_id , start_date , duration** 
. in this table remaining_days is default by **12** . so in input is decrease this (**remaining_days - duration**)

I want to create a paid leave module but I have problem, this table Paidleave is empty data , and if I create input I didnt have value to decrease this**duration**  , how I can create input data to table Paidleave without default value on this table ?

```
     public function store_Paidleave(Request $request)
    {

        $users = new Paidleave;
        $users->user_id              = $request->user_id ;
        $users->start_date           = $request->start_date  
        $users->duration             = $request->duration ;
        $cuti = DB::table('users')->select('users.Paidleaves')->get();
            if(Input::get('duration') < $cuti){
               return "cant input data"
            }
            elseif($cuti > Input::get('duration')){
                DB::table('users')->where('id', user_id)->decrement('cuti' , 
                Input::get('duration'));
            }
            else{
                return ('error , tidak ada input');
                return redirect()->back();
            }

        $users->save();
        return redirect ('Paidleave')->with('success', 'Input Succes');


    }
```

my problem is how I can set first 12 and decrease by duration and this value of new remaining_days is can input on remaining days column ?

**EDIT**

I have updated my question and still i didn't get my problem solved.

Comment: Best case is to create an entry in `PaidLeave` table at the time of user creation.Whenever a user applied for a leave create a new entry by using the previous entry (use remaining_days)

Comment: i update my coding . i add new colomn on Users table . please check and help me

Answer (score 0):

Assume you have created a new entry in `PaidLeave` table for a user whenever you created a user in `User` table.

```
public function store_Paidleave(Request $request)
{
$paid_leave = Paidleave::where('user_id','=',$request->user_id)->orderBy('created_at','DESC')->first();
if(sizeof($paid_leave))
{
$users = new Paidleave();
$users->user_id              = $paid_leave->user_id;
$remaining_days = $paid_leave->remaining_days - $request->duration; 
$users->remaining_days       = $remaining_days ;
$users->start_date           = $request->start_date  
$users->duration             = $request->duration ;
$users->save();
return redirect()->route('Paidleave')->with('success', 'Input Succes');
}
}
```

Comment: i have a question sir , in your code ,'user_id' = Auth::user  , but in my input  , this input is from admin , not from user login , how i can catch id from this ?

Comment: then use `$request->user_id`

Comment: nah , its can specified like this ? $cuti = DB::table('users')->select('users.Paidleaves')->where('user_id, request->user_id)get();   , like this ? or i get a fault ?

Comment: how about create new colomn in Users table

Comment: Users table is for users..so don't put duplicate entries